# Sort list in kotlin by variable property given as parameter

Tags: kotlin

I know it's possible to sort a list of person by a property using following syntax:

```
persons = persons.sortedBy { person: Person-> person.name }
```

Now i want to write a sort function which accepts the property by which i want the list to be sorted by as an parameter.

In `JavaScript` i would write something like this:

```
fun sort(property: String) { 
        persons = persons.sortedBy { person: Person-> person[property]} 
}
```

But i cannot write "person[property]" in `Kotlin`.

So how can i achieve such a sorting function in `Kotlin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i want to write a sort function which accepts the property by which i want the list to be sorted by as an parameter.

Let's hope that by "the property", you can settle for something like a function reference:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
  
var people = listOf(Person("Jane Doe", 25), Person("John Smith", 24), Person("Jen Jones", 37))

fun <R: Comparable<R>> sort(selector: (Person) -> R) {
  people = people.sortedBy(selector)
}

fun main() {
  println(people)
  sort(Person::name)
  println(people)
}
```

I could also use `sort(Person::age)` if I wanted to sort by age.

If your pseudocode is more literal, and you want a `String` parameter for the property name, you should start by asking yourself "why?". But, if you feel that you have a legitimate reason to use a `String`, one approach would be:

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
  
var people = listOf(Person("Jane Doe", 25), Person("John Smith", 24), Person("Jen Jones", 37))

fun sort(property: String) {
  people = when(property) {
    "name" -> people.sortedBy(Person::name)
    "age" -> people.sortedBy(Person::age)
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("and this is why you should not be doing this")
  }
}

fun main() {
  println(people)
  sort("name")
  println(people)
}
```

Comment: There is also a [description](https://bezkoder.com/kotlin-sort-list-objects/) for all possible variants. It is also possible to [sort by several fields](https://bezkoder.com/kotlin-sort-list-objects/#Sort_List_by_multiple_fields_in_Kotlin).

Comment: Yes, a selector function is the standard way of doing this; you can see many examples in the standard library.  As you demonstrate, providing a function _name_ is awkward and restrictive, as well as being a lot less flexible.  (You could also do something with reflection, but that's usually a very bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomObject(val customProperty: String, val value:Int)

 val list = ArrayList<CustomObject>()
        list.add(CustomObject("Z",5))
        list.add(CustomObject("A",4))
        list.add(CustomObject("B",1))
        list.add(CustomObject("X",6))
        list.add(CustomObject("Aa",7))

        var alphabeticallySortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy { it.customProperty })
        var numberWiseSortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy { it.value })
```